# What is the difference between empty() , isset() and is_null() function in php?

Tags: php, difference, isset

I did lot of research but was unable to find the difference between these three. So I have done a short example I hope that will we helpful.

Here is the tabular representation of all these three

```
Case             Empty()        isset()     is_null()
1. $a=NULL         1              0             1

2. Not exists      1              0         1/Warning

3. $a=''           1              1             0

4. $a='NULL'       0              1             0

5. $a='testing'    0              1             0
```

And here is the code to implement it .

Answer (score 3):

PHP has different functions which can be used to test the value of a variable. Three useful functions for this are `isset()`, `empty()` and `is_null()`. All these function return a boolean value. If these functions are not used in correct way they can cause unexpected results.

`isset()` and `empty()` are often viewed as functions that are opposite, however this is not always true.

`isset` — **Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL**

In other words, it returns true only when the variable is not null.

`empty` — **Determine whether a variable is empty**

In other words, it will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

`is_null` — **Finds whether a variable is NULL**

In other words, it returns true only when the variable is null. is_null() is opposite of isset(), except for one difference that isset() can be applied to unknown variables, but is_null() only to declared variables